# Error Field Typewith EE2.8 and Tinymce

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, fieldtype

Deprecated function EE_Fieldtype() called in system/expressionengine/third_party/nsm_tiny_mce/ft.nsm_tiny_mce.php on line 61.

When I try to create a new channel field I get this:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Fieldtype::EE_Fieldtype() in /home3/bartelsf/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/nsm_tiny_mce/ft.nsm_tiny_mce.php on line 61

I am using Tinymce 1.1.1 and updated to the most recent EE 2.8.1

Any thoughts would be very helpful!

Comment: Tomstuder I have same problem were can i get the fix you mentioned ? thanks

Comment: The fix is at EE Garage - Post a request into the support section. They should send you the files you need. I believe they mentioned they will have the updated files on the site soon.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine NSM TinyMCE hasn't been updated to work with recent versions of EE. You may need to try another Wysiwyg fieldtype instead. There are a number of them out there.

Comment: Based on my recent posts on this issue, I was given an update to nsm tinyMSE. This cleared the issues. The odd thing is that I tried to remove TinyMSE and for whatever reason, the CMS was still looking for it even after disabling TinyMSE and removing the posts that used it. All good now though.